# Doctype syntax error not resolving

Tags: doctype

I am facing doctype error, firefox developer toolbar showing error, while banner also not playing in IE, and same thing saying in IE as well, 
please have a look at URL and let me know what is error in doctype ?

http://cars.bugs3.com/

Thanks

Comment: try this <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: I tried, but no success